# Meltdown/Spectre fix on older windows PC

Tags: windows-7, dell-dimension, meltdown

I have a [Dell Dimension 4700](https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-dimension-4700-pentium-4-3ghz-512mb-ram-160gb-hdd-xp-home/specs/), running Windows 7 Home Premium (32 bit).
Per 'systeminfo', the CPU is "x86 Family 15 Model 4"

I believe that this is vulnerable to the Meltdown/Spectre problem.

WRT which, [Dell says](http://www.dell.com/support/contents/us/en/04/article/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/software-and-downloads/support-for-meltdown-and-spectre):

> There are essential components that need to be applied to mitigate the
>   above mentioned vulnerabilities:
>
> ```
> Apply the firmware update via BIOS update.
> Apply the applicable operating system (OS) patch.
> Apply hypervisor patches, browser and JavaScript engines updates where applicable.
> ```

AIUI, said 'firmware update' [comes from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025619/software.html), but then must be further refined and distributed by Dell.  However, Dell seems not to list *any* Dimension series in their [upgrade schedule](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln308237/dell-client-statement-on-intel-me-txe-advisory--intel-sa-00086-?lang=en).

Questions

1. Am I just misunderstanding this, and the Intel update is/will be available for this PC?
2. Is the Intel update somehow not applicable to this PC/CPU?
3. Given the order of the above Dell list, can I safely install the Windows 7 update?
4. Is the Win 7 update useful, without the firmware update?

Comment: [Correction.  The microcode is associated with Spectre not Meltdown.](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2018/01/09/understanding-the-performance-impact-of-spectre-and-meltdown-mitigations-on-windows-systems/)

Comment: Your processor is vulnerable to Meltdown, and one of the mitigation’s for Spectre requires a microcode, which means unless Dell releases a firmware update you won’t receive that microcode. The update should be installed because of the other associated Spectre vulnerability and of course the patch to protect you from Meltdown itself.

Comment: intel only patches CPUs which are at least Haswell generation (Core i 4xxxx): https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.heise.de%2Fnewsticker%2Fmeldung%2FMeltdown-und-Spectre-Intel-patcht-ab-2013-produzierte-Prozessoren-bestaetigt-Performance-Auswirkung-3936956.html&edit-text=

Comment: Try [InSpectre](https://www.grc.com/inspectre.htm) - easily examine and understand any Windows system's hardware and software capability to prevent Meltdown and Spectre attacks.